# Getting weird format when trying to update rails column array type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to update a column called needs that is the following:

```
t.text "needs", default: "{}"
```

I went through a couple migration to try and make it work and I still get the same error. It does not update the column and it looks like it reformats the data inside my api call. Here is what I get from the rails server:

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"birthdate"=>"2019-07-30T11:59:31.215Z", "needs"=>["relationship", "life", "general"], "coach_gender"=>""}, "id"=>"15"}

UPDATE "users" SET "needs" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["needs", "[\"relationship\", \"life\", \"general\"]"], ["updated_at", "2019-07-30 12:08:12.013589"], ["id", 15]]
```

Then when I try do get the first need from the user like so:

```
User.needs.first
```

I get

```
"["
```

My controller looks like this:

```
def edit
  User.find_by(id: params[:id]).update_attributes(user_params)
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :birthdate, :description, :email, :password, :coach_gender, :needs => [])
end
```

Comment: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/07/rails-4-and-postgresql-arrays/ according to this. It should be t.text :tags, array: true, default: []

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think it is weird to get `"["` when doing `User.needs.first`? `User.needs` holds `text` and the first character of your sample text is `"["`. Seems perfectly normal.

What seems weird (to me) is that you're using a text datatype to store an array without any serialization. Or, alternatively, using a native `array` datatype (as with PostgreSQL) doing something like:

```
t.string 'needs', array: true
```

...in your migration (see the [guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array) for more information).

It also seems weird (to me) that the default for the supposed array appears to be a hash (`default: "{}"`).

I also wonder why you're not using a `Need` model and creating a M:M relationship between `User` and `Need`. Something, perhaps, like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: needs
#
#  id               :bigint           not null, primary key
#  name             :string
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#
class Need < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_needs
  has_many :users, through: :user_needs
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: user_needs
#
#  id               :bigint           not null, primary key
#  user_id          :integer
#  need_id          :integer
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#
class UserNeed < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :need
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_needs
  has_many :needs, through: :user_needs
end
```

Which will make querying easier down the road. Like, "give me all users that have a life need" could be something like:

```
Need.find_by(name: 'life').users
```

Comment: that's what I got after doing the migration to add a default value of [] to the column.

Comment: Perhaps you should add your migration to your question as that seems to be a part of the problem. Also, do you expect to accept any sort of user-defined need (e.g., a user could state their need as "Foo")? Or, do you want the needs to be standardized?

Comment: I want the needs to be standardized but the needs comes from the client and the options are restricted. I managed to fix this by deleting my migrations and inserting t.text "needs", array: true,  default: [] directly inside the migration that creates the table user and then deleting the schema and regenerating it and also regenerating the database.

Comment: If needs come from the client and the options are restricted, then I really don't understand why you're using an array instead of an association. But, hey, to each their own.

Comment: Because I don't need to access them, it's not a main feature.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
t.text "needs", array: true,  default: "{}"
```

Comment: Add add_column :users, :needs, :text, array: true, default: '{}' in the migration still results in the schema t.text "needs", default: "{}". I'm missing the array: true.